# EU travel suggestions between 12/26 and 1/15

Tags: europe

I'm planning an EU trip with my family and would love to hear thoughts or suggestions on where to go, with a few things in mind that I'll explain below. It'll be my wife and I, my 5 kids ages 3 months to 9 years, and my parents (so 4 adults 5 kids).

We arrive in Amsterdam Nov 15 and stay for a few days, then train to Hamburg -> train to Copenhagen -> overnight ferry to Oslo -> train to Stockholm -> overnight ferry to Helsinki -> fly to Prague for Christmas (Dec 19 - 26). We stay in each place between 4 and 7 days.

We're trying to figure out where to go after Prague. Constraints are:

1. Trying to keep costs reasonable (under $200/night if possible)
2. Avoiding Italy and Zurich as we've already been there. Staying in Airbnbs the entire time (so far).
3. Travel times of ~6 hours or less preferred
4. We'd like to make it to Brussels by 1/8 or so to check it out before we fly out of Amsterdam on 1/15

Places we've considered so far:

1. Vienna - prices are quite high near 12/31 though
2. Salzburg - prices are extremely high ($450+ per night) - probably not an option
3. Budapest - somewhat expensive for this time of year, and puts us further away from Brussels

Maybe we need to head more West?

1. Munich is a 6.5 hr train ride away
2. But Munich to Paris is 9-10 hours

Would like to see at least some part of France, if not Paris, before heading up to Brussels.

Complicated question but would love any thoughts. We're quite open-minded within the constraints I mentioned.

Comment: As you already have flights in your itinerary, is there any reason not to consider more flights? You could get to about anywhere in Europe (and beyond) in less than 6 hours. Note however that in many places New Year’s Eve means special rates and/or rules, especially in the larger cities.

Comment: Since we have so many people it's fairly expensive. Best flight I can find from Helsinki to Prague is $110 each. I expect we'll have 3 bags to check among us as well. But we're still open to it.

Comment: It’s not like train tickets are especially cheap, especially on log distance and/or high speed trains. There are currently flights from Prague to Barcelona for 85 euros/pax on the 26th for instance. Probably not the right destination for cheap hotels on New Year’s Eve, but it illustrates the travel options.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind! I did see group rates for 6+ on trains. Around 20 euros per person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **[Prag Hbf -> Nürnberg Hbf](https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/dn?ld=37231&protocol=https:&seqnr=1&ident=lo.024684231.1572551522&rt=1&OK#focus)** (26.12.19)

  - 4 hours 34 minutes, 1 change in Cheb with 10 minutes to transfer
- **[Nürnberg Hbf -> Paris Est](https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/dn?revia=yes&existOptimizePrice=1&country=DEU&lang=de&dbkanal_007=L01_S01_D001_KSO0001_-_OBEN_LZ03&start=1&tariffClass=2&S=N%C3%BCrnberg+Hbf&REQ0JourneyStopsSID=&Z=Paris+Est&REQ0JourneyStopsZID=&date=01.01.20&time=06%3A00&externRequest=yes&HWAI=JS%21js%3Dyes%21ajax%3Dyes%21)** (01.01.20)

  - 6 hours 25 minutes, 1 change in Stuttgart with 56 minutes wait

The 26th of December is a holiday in Germany .
Since Silvester (New Year) is a big celebration

- an early **reservation** for the night of 31.12 to 01.01 would have to be made.